# How to create drag and reorder grid view item in flutter without using any package?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create drag and reorder grid view item in flutter without using any package?

I want create grid view with user can reorder its item. but there is no custom way available
and there are only few packages are there

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I know what you mean, but you can use the `Draggable()` Widget to make something dragable. Just put a container in there and you can drag it.

Then, you can use the `DragTarget()` Widget with a container child to allow a `Draggable()` to be dragged on top of it.
You can use the onAccept method to define what happens when a `Draggable()` Widget gets dragged on top of there.

Comment: I want to reorder the  position of grid view item